# How can I print the shortest path between two vertices in a graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a working implementation of Djikstra's algorithm which calculates the length of the shortest path between any two nodes. But if I need to find the actual path, how can I print that? Thanks!

```
void djikstra( graph * mygraph )
{
    int dist[100] = {INT_MAX};
    int i;
    //int parent[mygraph->vertices] = {-99};
    for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        dist[i] = INT_MAX;
    bool arr[100];
    for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        arr[i] = false;
    int foo;
    cout<<"Enter the source vertex\n";
    cin>>foo;
    dist[foo] = 0;  
    vector<int> bar;
    while (bar.size() != mygraph->vertices)
    {
        int node = findmin(dist,mygraph->vertices,arr);
        arr[node] = true; // so that again and again same node having minimum distance is not returned
        bar.push_back(node);
        auto it = mygraph->edges[node].begin();
        while (it != mygraph->edges[node].end())
        {
            relax(node,it->first,it->second,dist); // here, it->first represents the node and it->second represents the weight
            it++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Vertex\t"<<"Distance from source\n";
    for ( i = 0; i < mygraph->vertices; i++ )
    {
        cout<<i<<"\t"<<dist[i]<<"\n";
    }   
    cout<<"\n";
    return;
}

void relax ( int node, int a, int w, int dist[] )
{
    if (dist[a] > dist[node] + w)
    {
        dist[a] = dist[node] + w;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not clear about this question? Voting to reopen.

Comment: @juanchopanza `I have a working implementation of Djikstra's algorithm which calculates the length of the shortest path between any two nodes. But if I need to find the actual path, how can I print that?` What is not clear? He has a dijkstra's implementation working. He wants the path, and not only the distance from source to target. Perfectly clear for anyone slightly familiar with graphs and shortest path problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza Also, closing a question without a single comment to let the OP knows what's wrong in it? how will he ask better questions?

Comment: @amit So what does "But if I need to find the actual path, how can I print that?" mean?

Comment: @juanchopanza Find the actual path. What's not clear? a path `v1->v2->..vk` such that minimizes the cost of the distance between `v1` and `vk`, for some given `v1,vk`. Are you familiar with shortest path problem?

Comment: @amit It isn't asking to find the path. It is asking if finding the path is needed, how to print it. That makes no sense. Are you familiar with the English language?

Comment: ..well that escalated quickly... ;)

Comment: @juanchopanza If you are so picky about the word "print", try asking clarifications before closing a question.  I am sorry if this question is too complex to comprehend because it's not "What X operator do?" (or something else very technical), but it's perfectly clear for anyone familiar with the shortest path problem and algorithms. Glad the community agrees with me after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to also keep a map, which maps from a node, to its "parent".

In this map, the key is a node, and the value is the node used to reach this map.

Obviously the source is going to be a root in this map.

This is done by adding:

```
parentMap[a] = node;
```

In the relaxation step:

```
void relax ( int node, int a, int w, int dist[] )
{
    if (dist[a] > dist[node] + w)
    {
        dist[a] = dist[node] + w;
        parentMap[a] = node;
    }
}
```

Once you have this map, getting the path is farily easy, and is done by:

```
int current = target;
while (current != source) { 
   cout << current << ' ';
   current = parentMap[current];
}
cout << current << ' ';
```

Note, the above prints the path in reverse order. You can use a list (and add elements to its front rather than printing the elements) to get the path in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

You can trace back your path through parent node.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class solution{
public:
    void printPath(vector<int> parent, int source, int dest)
    {
        stack<int> st;
        int final = dest;
        while(parent[dest] != source)
        {
            dest = parent[dest];
            st.push(dest);
        }
        cout<<source<<"->";
        while(!st.empty())
        {
            cout<<st.top()<<"->";
            st.pop();
        }
        cout<<final<<endl;
    }

    void shortestPath(int V, vector<pair<int, int>> G[], int source, int dest)
    {
        vector<int> dist(V, INT_MAX);
        dist[source] = 0;
        queue<int> q;
        q.push(source);
        vector<int> parent(V, -1);
        parent[source] = source;
        while(!q.empty())
        {
            int u = q.front();
            q.pop();
            for(auto node: G[u])
            {
                int v = node.first;
                int wt = node.second;
                if(dist[v] > dist[u]+wt)
                {
                    dist[v] = dist[u]+wt;
                    q.push(v);
                    parent[v] = u;
                }
            }
        }

        cout<<"Cost to reach destination: "<<dist[dest]<<"\n";
        printPath(parent, source, dest);
    }
};

int main(){
    int V, E, source, dest;
    cout<<"Enter # of Vertex : ";
    cin>>V;
    cout<<"Enter # of Edges : ";
    cin>>E;
    int u, v, wt;
    cout<<"Add Edges ->\n";
    vector<pair<int, int>> adj[V];
    while(E--)
    {
        cin>>u>>v>>wt;
        adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, wt));
    }
    cout<<"Enter Source : ";
    cin>>source;
    cout<<"Enter Destination :";
    cin>>dest;
    solution* obj = new solution;
    obj->shortestPath(V, adj, source, dest);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code looks like this,

```
Enter # of Vertex : 6
Enter # of Edges : 8
Add Edges ->
0 1 2
1 2 5
2 3 5
3 4 5
4 1 50
4 5 600
1 5 1000
2 4 1
Enter Source : 0
Enter Destination :5
Cost to reach destination: 608
0->1->2->4->5
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest Path-Printing using Dijkstra's Algorithm for Graph (Here it is implemented for undirected Graph. The following code prints the shortest distance from the source_node to all the other nodes in the graph.

> > **It also prints the shortest path from the source node to the node requested by the user.**
> >     Suppose,you need to find the shortest path from **A** to **B** in the graph. Then input **A** as the source node and **B** as the destination node.

**Code**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define INF (unsigned)!((int)0)

const int MAX=2e4;
vector<pair<int,int>> graph[MAX];

bool visit[MAX];
int dist[MAX];

multiset<pair<int,int>> s;
int parent[MAX];                                 // used to print the path

int main(){
    memset(visit,false,sizeof(visit));
    memset(dist,INF,sizeof(dist));
    memset(parent,-1,sizeof(parent));

    int nodes,edges;        cin>>nodes>>edges;
    for(auto i=0;i<edges;++i){
        int a,b,w;
        cin>>a>>b>>w;
        graph[a].push_back(make_pair(b,w));
        graph[b].push_back(make_pair(a,w));   //Comment it to make the Directed Graph
    }
    int source_node;    cin>>source_node;
    dist[source_node]=0;
    s.insert(make_pair(0,source_node));

    while(!s.empty()){
        pair<int,int> elem=*s.begin();
        s.erase(s.begin());
        int node=elem.second;
        if(visit[node])continue;
        visit[node]=true;
        for(auto i=0;i<graph[node].size();++i){
            int dest=graph[node][i].first;
            int w=graph[node][i].second;
            if(dist[node]+w<dist[dest]){
                dist[dest]=dist[node]+w;
                parent[dest]=node;
                s.insert(make_pair(dist[dest],dest));
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"NODE"<<"         "<<"DISTANCE"<<endl;
    for(auto i=1;i<=nodes;++i){
        cout<<i<<"         "<<dist[i]<<endl;
    }
    /*----PRINT SHORTEST PATH FROM THE SOURCE NODE TO THE NODE REQUESTED-------*/
    int node_for_path;      cin>>node_for_path;
    int dest_node=node_for_path;
    stack<int> path;
    while(parent[node_for_path]!=source_node){
        path.push(node_for_path);
        node_for_path=parent[node_for_path];
    }
    path.push(node_for_path);
    path.push(source_node);
    cout<<"Shortest Path from "<<source_node<<"to "<<dest_node<<":"<<endl;
    while(!path.empty()){
        if(path.size()==1) cout<<path.top();
        else cout<<path.top()<<"->";
        path.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
/*TEST CASE*/
9 14        //---NODES,EDGES---
1 2 4       //---START,END,WEIGHT---FOR THE NO OF EDGES
2 3 8
3 4 7
4 5 9
5 6 10
6 7 2
7 8 1
8 1 8
2 8 11
8 9 7
9 7 6
9 3 2
6 3 4
4 6 14
1           //---SOURCE_NODE
5           //-----NODE TO WHICH PATH IS REQUIRED
---END---*/
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

based on @Dipesh Kurasau above, I have done some code below:
Ouput is: total distance =400. Path: 0 5.
If you comment out v0.adjacents.emplace(&v5, 400); you get the same result as @Dipesh Kurasau.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex(int i) : id(i) {}
    int id;
    int toSrcVertex = INT_MAX; // initial distance from this vertex to the source vertex
    Vertex* prev = NULL;       // point to the previous vertex leading to the source vertex making the shortest path
    unordered_map<Vertex*, int> adjacents; //adjacent vertex and its distance;
};

void printPath(Vertex* destination)
{
    cout << "total distance =" << destination->toSrcVertex << endl;
    cout << "Path:" << endl;
    stack<Vertex*> reversed;

    while (destination)
    {
        reversed.push(destination);
        destination = destination->prev;
    }

    while (!reversed.empty())
    {
        Vertex* t = reversed.top();
        reversed.pop();
        cout << t->id << " ";
    }

    cout << "\ndone" << std::flush << endl;
}

void shortest(Vertex* src, Vertex* dest)
{
    src->toSrcVertex = 0;
    unordered_set<Vertex*> q;
    q.insert(src);

    unordered_set<Vertex*> visited;

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        Vertex* u = *(q.begin());
        q.erase(q.begin());

        if (q.empty() && u == dest)
        {
            // target reached, no more search
            return;
        }

        // vistit all adjacents of Vertex u
        for(auto& adj : u->adjacents)
        {
            Vertex* adjVertex = adj.first;

            if (visited.find(adjVertex) != visited.end()) continue;

            int distance = adj.second;

            int distanceFromUtoAdjVertex = distance + u->toSrcVertex;

            if (distanceFromUtoAdjVertex < adjVertex->toSrcVertex)
            {
                adjVertex->toSrcVertex = distanceFromUtoAdjVertex;
                adjVertex->prev = u;
                q.insert(adjVertex);
            }
        }

        visited.insert(u);
    }

    printPath(dest);
}

int main()
{
    // construct vertices
    Vertex v0(0);
    Vertex v1(1);
    Vertex v2(2);
    Vertex v3(3);
    Vertex v4(4);
    Vertex v5(5);

    // build adjacents (neighboured vertex and distance)
    v0.adjacents.emplace(&v1, 2);
    v0.adjacents.emplace(&v5, 400);

    v1.adjacents.emplace(&v0, 2);
    v1.adjacents.emplace(&v2, 5);
    v1.adjacents.emplace(&v4, 50);
    v1.adjacents.emplace(&v5, 1000);

    v2.adjacents.emplace(&v1, 5);
    v2.adjacents.emplace(&v3, 5);
    v2.adjacents.emplace(&v4, 1);

    v3.adjacents.emplace(&v2, 5);
    v3.adjacents.emplace(&v4, 5);

    v4.adjacents.emplace(&v2, 1);
    v4.adjacents.emplace(&v3, 5);
    v4.adjacents.emplace(&v1, 50);
    v4.adjacents.emplace(&v5, 600);

    v5.adjacents.emplace(&v1, 1000);
    v5.adjacents.emplace(&v4, 600);

    shortest(&v0, &v5);

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n" << flush << endl;;
}
```